# How to select * from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, table1 and table2. table1 has 2 rows. table2 has 3 rows. so, totally table1 and table2 have 5 rows. I want to show the 5 rows by selecting table1 and table2 at a time. how todo? can you help me please. don't add any where clause.

Comment: If table have the same structure you can use `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2`

Comment: Thanks show much. immediately you responded me. it works great.

Comment: Yaseen if my answer solves your issue I'd greatly appreciate it if you [**marked it as accepted**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33430090/2733506) so this question can be considered resolved / closed. I'll throw you a +1 because were all here for reputation as well :)

Answer (score 1):

depends on what the table structure is. if you have a PK > FK relationship you can join the tables like so

```
SELECT stuff
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.someID = t2.someID
```

if there is no correlation then you can use a UNION

```
SELECT stuff 
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT stuff
FROM table2
```

One thing to note about using a UNION. the columns have to match so if you have the same type of data in both tables this works fine or else you will have to specify which columns to be selected out.